# Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment-project

[image: /clear .]

an error occurs after adding this piece of code

```
Artisan::call('route:cache');
```

in this function

```
 //cache clear pack
    Route::get('/clear', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:cache');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return "All Cache cleared!!";
});
```

Comment: Can you show your routes, please? Particularly the `api/user` route

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can not cache, **closures based routes** therefore you will need to change any closures(If there are any closures on your route file) to call methods on controllers.

Details can be found here https://paulund.co.uk/laravel-routing-tips

try to have them in a Command class:
`php artisan make:command myCache`